# How to mirror mysql database traffic to another server

Tags: mysql, iptables

I have two server Mysql database in Cent OS 7. Server A(192.168.0.1) is live server and server B(192.168.0.2) is test server. I want to  mirror traffic from server A to server B. I used this Commands:

```
Server A) iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 3306  -j TEE --gateway 192.168.0.2
Server A) iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 3306  -j TEE --gateway 192.168.0.2

Server B) iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1 --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.2
```

My problem exist in server B. In server B when i see `tcpdump` on port 3306 i see same packet on server A. In other word result of `tcpdump` on both server is same.

I searching several days in web and i tried several solution. One of the solution is  [define](https://serverfault.com/questions/690470/rewrite-destination-ip-of-teeed-traffic) address IP of server A in server B on lo interface. I did it but did not work. Mysql in server B not hit packet and i can not see any established connection.

I see [this](https://github.com/agnoster/duplicator) page and used it but this solution has overhead on server A and number of connection is 3 times.

Is there solution for my problem ?

Comment: You can't just copy/mirror the traffic going to one server to another server and hoping it will work. In theory this can only work when the MySQL servers are in the **exact** same state so the received TCP packages on server B makes sense to server B and its state. If you want to run a stress test, do it not with the live traffic on your live server, but instead use any stress test application/tool of your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to keep the two servers' databases in sync, why not just use MySQL replication and make Server B a replica/slave to Server A?

At least in that scenario if a connection faults and replication is stopped (or temporarily lagged), it can be repaired and the replica can be brought up to sync with the master.  If you lose a network connection between Server A and Server B and you're simply "spraying" Server B with duplicated network traffic from Server A - there's no guarantee that your data sets will really remain in sync.

Check the docs for configuring replication between the two servers:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

Comment: I want to apply  stress test. In live database there are many connection in same time but in replication mode connection is less. The live mysql server version is 5.5 and test server is 8. I want to migration to version 8 but i want firstly check stress test. For me same connections is important and response and sync data with server live not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do this by mirroring TCP streams.

You need an additional "outboard" tool, either a proxy designed for such a purpose (if there is such a thing -- I am skeptical of this strategy, since such an approach would unnecessarily complicate the production environment, but it could be made to work) or something along the lines of [Percona Query Playback](https://github.com/Percona-Lab/query-playback/blob/master/README.md)¹ which uses the MySQL Slow Query Log to capture each query from the active server as soon as it finishes, and replay it on the secondary server.

The [Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) is used -- I suspect -- because it has a cleaner, easier-to-parse format than the [General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html), which is very difficult to machine-parse and does not provide as much useful information.

Setting `@@long_query_time` to `0` persuades MySQL Server to consider *all* queries as meeting the criteria for "slow" and thus eligible to be written to the slow log.

You could also use this same strategy to design your own utility to accomplish exactly the same purpose -- read the logs by tailing this file, and submit the queries for execution on the secondary server using a pool of client threads (for appropriate parallelism).

---

¹ *Percona Query Playback* is intended as an example, not an endorsement.  I have read about this utility, but do not recall whether or not I have actually used it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I concluded that with iptables, I can not do this because I need to create a session between the test server and the client machine.

I decided to use [proxysql](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/blob/v1.4.3/doc/mirroring.md) because this utility has mirror traffic tools.

Thanks